# Does irrlicht support boost and c++11 standard for mobile devices?

Tags: game-engine, irrlicht

I want to switch to new c++/lua game engine far away from marmalade and I choose irrlicht.
Does irrlicht support boost and c++11 standard for mobile devices ?
What is practice, to use containers provided by irrlicht or stl/boost?

Answer (score 0):

Irrlicht supports mobile devices(not sure about Androids though as it is Java based). Irrlicht is designed to support powerful rendering across all platforms. As there is no problem with old c++ versions, there won't be any compatibility issues with c++11.